# Typing for repl/infinite-loop type

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Let's say I have a function such as the following:

```
def echo() -> NoReturn: # correct?
    while True:
        val = input('echo> ')
        print (val)
```

What would be the correct [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for this? Would this more along the lines of `None` or `NoReturn` or something else?

Comment: `raw_input` means this is python2.7 which reached its end of life over a year ago. But you tagged the question with python3.x...

Comment: `raw_input` :O That's Python2

Comment: @h4z3 sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, so how can you `type` it? `-> None`?

Comment: Static type checking has nothing to do with the dynamic input of a user, so it adds nothing here. Your function doesn't return anything

Comment: @roganjosh so would you suggest just not adding anything here? Wouldn't NoReturn be correct also then?

Comment: mmm. It might be a novel question if you frame it that way. I think it's `NoReturn` but I'm not an aficionado on typing

Comment: @Simon why? It doesn't return

Comment: @roganjosh, he's just asking the return type. then it should be None though it never escape from the loop.

Comment: @Simon but `NoReturn` is also in `typing` so are you guessing here or do you know (you deleted your comment)?

Comment: @roganjosh, you are correct.

Comment: It can also be: ->type(None)